# Chrome not showing Saved Passwords on my mac

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

When clicked on any of the saved password from autofill it generally gives popup to authenticate and then show password.
Recently it stopped and not I can not see my saved passwords.
Can someone please help me with this issue?